# Will RAM manage the peripherals or they will have separate memory?

Tags: kernel, ram, vga

In a LINUX system the Virtual Address Space is **4GB** here as the Physical Memory depends on the RAM which we are using. For example I have a system of **1GB** RAM and my Monitor requires 256MB in-order to address it's pixels. Will the RAM take care of it or the monitor will have it's own memory that can access the **Kernel Module** directly?

Comment: Discrete graphics cards have their own memory, and integrated graphics chipsets steal some system ram.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Elaborate what?  You seem to be asking whether your video memory uses part of your main ram or not.  I said it does if you have an integrated graphics chip, and does not if you have a discrete graphics card.

Comment: Okay Thank you. In the same manner all peripheral devices (such as keyboard, mouse) will be addressed by our main RAM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, your monitor itself does not "require" certain amounts of RAM, but your GPU might. Also, RAM cannot manage anything other than some very low-level functions within itself.

When your system boots up, the BIOS or EFI will decide how much (if any) RAM your integrated GPU will need and "hard reserve" it from your system RAM to be used exclusively by the GPU.